# Estimate the norm of block matrix [(1-r)I,rI;-rI,A+rI]

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

Given a stochastic matrix of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, say $\mathcal{A}(t)$. Let
$$
S(t)=\begin{bmatrix} (1-r)I& rI\\-rI&rI+\mathcal{A}(t) \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $r\in(0,1)$, $I$ is the identity matrix of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Estimate the spectral radius of $S(t)$. (About $\mathcal{A}(t)$, we only known that it is stochastic)

What I have tried is the following:

Let $S_{11}(t)=I-rI,S_{12}(t)=rI=-S_{21}(t),S_{22}(t)=rI+\mathcal{A}(t)$.
Define $s(t)=[\|S_{ij}(t)\|_2]$. I use the spectral radius of $s(t)$, which is $1+\sqrt{2}r$ as the estimate of spectral radius of $S(t)$. But in the estimation, the sign of $S_{21}(t)$ have been ignored, which causes the conservativeness of this estimation.

So I wonder if there is a better estimation for the spectral radius.

Comment: What is $\|X\|_2$, is it the Schatten-2 norm, i.e., $\|X\|_2= \mathrm{tr}[X^T X]^{1/2}$?

Comment: Also what have you tried?

Comment: Actually, it is the spectral radius. I have updated the problem, see above, there is also what I have tried, which I am not sure if is OK.